# Building Rails Nested Form Within Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a rails form that includes a parent, child, and a child of the child. I'm using the nested_form gem and my rails version is 4.1. The issue I'm encountering is with a nested form with a nested field within it. I don't want to have the user add the nested resource with a button, but I want the nested object to be instantiated when the view loads.

**Parent Model**

```
class LoanApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  has_many :business_contacts, :dependent => :destroy

  # Nested Object 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_contacts, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Child of Parent**

```
class BusinessContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :loan_application
  has_one :personal_guarantee

  # Nested objects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_guarantee, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Child of Child (Grandchild to Parent)**

```
class PersonalGuarantee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :business_contact
end
```

**View**

```
<%= f.fields_for :business_contacts, :wrapper => true do |contact_form| %>
    <%= contact_form.fields_for :personal_guarantee do |guarantee| %>
        <%= guarantee.text_field :guarantor_net_worth %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The business_Contacts fields show up fine, but the child of business_contacts aren't showing up. I've nested the personal_guarantee fields in the params hash of loan_application_controller.

**loan_application_controller.rb**

```
def loan_applications_params
  params.require(:loan_application).permit(:loan_application_id, business_contacts_attributes: [:id, :business_salesforce_id, :prefix, :first_name, :exp_revenue_growth, :last_name, :business_title, :is_employee, :equity_hurdle, :contact_railsid, :guarantor_gender, :guarantor_sin_number, :guarantor_date_of_birth, :guarantor_phone_number, :guarantor_street_address, :guarantor_city, :guarantor_postal_code, :guarantor_province, :_destroy, personal_guarantee_attributes: [:id, :guarantor_net_worth]]
end
```

As I mentioned above, with the above setup, I can't see to see the PersonalGuarantee field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

According the rails guides [fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) expects the options hash to be the third param, the second is the object or nil. Please try this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :business_contacts, nil, :wrapper => true do |contact_form| %>
```

Also, I think, all the objects at the form are built.